# apache mod rewrite cookie propagation

Tags: apache

I am trying this out in my local windows machine.

I have the apache httpd set up which redirects to tomcat.

Apache httpd runs on 9000 and I have two tomcats hosting different applications running on 8080 and 9090 ports in the same machine.

Below is my scenario

http://:9000/mypage1?id=XYZ must be redirected to Tomcat 1 as http://:8080/myappp1/mypage1 
http://:9000/mypage2?id=ABC must be redirected to Tomcat 2 as http://:9090/myappp2/mypage2

I am able to access the query parameter and do the redirection using mod_jk.

When the user access the first application , a cookie is set by the Tomcat 1 . When the subsequent request goes to Tomcat 1 ,the cookie values are available.

When the user acess the second application , the cookie values set by Tomcat 1 are not available in Tomcat 2 . I need the cookie values in myapp2 running in tomcat 2.

My understanding is that since from the browser , the call is always to http://:9000 , the cookie should be send during redirection to both the tomcats .

When I enable cookie information in httpd logs ,I see it gets printed only when redirection happens to Tomcat 1

Kindly explain if my requirement is not feasible or if there are any work arounds

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution .
While setting the cookie , I set the cookie path as "/" .